# Intel modesetting driver screen tearing

Tags: xorg, intel

I am facing tearing issue when XORG using Intel modesetting driver. Does anyone else face this issue? If anyone has solution please help me out.

I have also tried intel driver with

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Intel Graphics"
  Driver "intel"
  Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

but it end-up having crash.

```
[141003.247] (EE) Backtrace:
[141003.248] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4d) [0x555cafab98fd]
[141003.248] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x555caf8fc000+0x1c1a1a) [0x555cafabda1a]
[141003.248] (EE) 2: /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fc07c202000+0x13340) [0x7fc07c215340]
[141003.248] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7fc07ba02000+0x6d882) [0x7fc07ba6f882]
[141003.249] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7fc07ba02000+0xb3f91) [0x7fc07bab5f91]
[141003.249] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7fc07ba02000+0xb20cc) [0x7fc07bab40cc]
[141003.249] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so (0x7fc07ba02000+0x7e45d) [0x7fc07ba8045d]
[141003.250] (EE) 7: /usr/bin/Xorg (AddScreen+0x8e) [0x555caf94b8fe]
[141003.250] (EE) 8: /usr/bin/Xorg (InitOutput+0x670) [0x555caf9904c0]
[141003.250] (EE) 9: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x555caf8fc000+0x53708) [0x555caf94f708]
[141003.251] (EE) 10: /lib/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xeb) [0x7fc07c068b5b]
[141003.251] (EE) 11: /usr/bin/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x555caf93893a]
[141003.251] (EE)
[141003.251] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x11
```

Comment: the only thing that works for me is using a compositor like picom

Answer (score 3):

The intel Xorg driver has long been deprecated and is not recommended to use and for the proper modesetting driver you should have this configuration:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "modesetting"
    Driver "modesetting"
    Option "TearFree" "True"
EndSection
```

Though I'm not sure this feature has made it to the official Xorg release. More info here: https://www.mupuf.org/blog/2018/09/24/teaching_x_modesetting_new_tricks/

Still a crash mustn't happen. Please report a bug here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/wikis/How-to-file-i915-bugs

Comment: Are there any updates here? Judging from the thread in the PR (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/merge_requests/24), it seems the patch was never incorporated

Comment: I'm using this exact configuration on Fedora 36 with Intel graphics and I've got no tearing.

Comment: Are you using `picom`? I got over the tearing with picom, but without it, this .conf above does nothing.

Comment: Merged [2 weeks ago](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/merge_requests/1006). The option should be available in xserver 21.1.7, or something.

Comment: "TearFree" isn't in 21.1.10 either.  It will come with the next major version release date for which is unknown.  It will actually be enabled by default ([commit](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/commit/0dacee6c5)).